# Discord bot retrieve pins from all channels

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my Bot to post pins from all 6 channels in this server, however, my bot only gets pins from the current channel where the command is called. I am wondering if there is a way around this. Discord version 1.0.0A

The code I have at the moment is:

```py
    if "seepins()" == message.content.lower():
        # retrieve and post all pins again
        allPins = await message.channel.pins()
        for i in allPins:
            # Check if pin is text or a link
            mat = i.attachments
            if len(mat)==0:
                await message.channel.send(i.content)
            else:
                await message.channel.send(mat[0].url)
```

The following code retrieves user details from all servers where this bot is present. I'm wondering if guild should be used instead of channel in the first code snippet? This gave me an error as a result.

````py
 if "member_status()" == message.content.lower():
        online = 0
        idle = 0
        offline = 0
        print(f"Testing the API with guild.owner: {guild}")
        for i in guild.members:
            if str(i.status) == "online":
                online +=1
            elif str(i.status) == "offline":
                offline +=1
            else:
                idle +=1
        await message.channel.send(f"```py\ntotal: {guild.member_count} \nonline: {online}  \nidle: {idle}  \noffline: {offline}```")
````

Comment: I haven't worked with `1.0.0a` before, but looking at the docs it seems that `guild` has indeed a `channels` iterable which does what you might be looking for (see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.channels)). You can try and see if it works with `message.guild.channels` and then calling `pins()` on each channel in a loop. Be careful though, as it seems that `channels` also includes all kinds of channels like voice channels and not just text channels, so you might have to add a type check for `TextChannel` as well.

Comment: Thanks Xay that worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out thanks to Xay's comment.
What you have to do is retrieve all channels using

```py
message.guild.text_channels
```

which returns a list of all text channels.
Then you iterate through each channel and retrieve the list of pins present in each channel using

```py
myPins = await mychannel.pins()
```

It may not be the most efficient code but it does the job :)
and finally iterate again to repost each pin from that channel.

The code at final looks like:

```py
    if "getAllPins()" == message.content.lower():
        # get all channels
        allChannels = message.guild.text_channels
        # go through each channel
        for myChannel in allChannels:
            # get pins present in this channel
            myPins = await mychannel.pins()
            # re-post all the pins
            for rePin in myPins:
                mat = rePin.attachments
                if len(mat)==0:
                    await message.channel.send(rePin.content)
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(mat[0].url)
```